# How to get recent versions of packages for Ubuntu 14.04 LTS?

Tags: 14.04, package-management

Good morning!

I've installed Ubuntu 14.04 on my PC. And I observe that many packages have latest versions actual for the 2014. For example, I observe gcc 4.9.2 and git 1.9. I know that they have already more recent versions like gcc 5.3 and git 2.7. But I can't get them through the packages manager.

My Ubuntu receives some updates for kernel and some system libraries. So I see that updating procedure is working and a repository is updating. But what's going on with non-system packages?

Of course I can get a source code tarball and build a program from sources. But I'm interesting in getting true packages. I believe that packaging of git or gcc didn't stop in 2014.

How to fix settings of my Ubuntu to get them?

Answer (score 0):

Go to **Software & Updates.**
There , you will find a tab named **Other Softwares**
You will find repositories which are unchecked and are related to the softwares installed.  Enable those and run update again.
Hope it helps.

Comment: I've already did this. And updated local lists from repositories. But still see "git-all/trusty-updates,trusty-security 1:1.9.1-1ubuntu0.2 all" while typing "apt search git". This package was related to 2014 I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

The best option is to go to Launchpad and find a relevant PPA. Follow instructions for installing on your system.

You can go to the package website and download directly but you can get overwhelmed in trying to meet all the dependencies. With a PPA someone else has done all that for you.

Comment: Thanks. I not feel myself very confident with PPAs. How they are related to offitial Ubuntu repository? Do they reference to it (in case of dependencies)?

If I would install Ubuntu 15, do I get an official repository with more recent versions of packages? Of course I will not do this, but I'm just interesting whether Ubuntu 14.04's repository and Ubuntu 15's repository are completely different ones?

So whether I understand correctly that for every fresh package (which Ubuntu 15 users have in official repository) I need to add one more PPA?